# How can I edit the source of HTML in the clipboard?

Tags: desktop-environments, clipboard

If I cut some HTML from a Pidgin instant messenger window, I can easily paste it verbatim into a new HTML email in Thunderbird. All formatting (fonts, colors, etc) are preserved, so it appears that my Ubuntu 13.10 desktop clipboard must have the HTML source somewhere.

But I'd like to tweak the HTML source.

How can I actually get at the HTML source when it is in the clipboard? I'd like to just throw it into a text file, work on the markup in Vim or whatever, then use this HTML source in a webpage or feed it to Thunderbird's "Insert → HTML".

Hmm, maybe something like [PasteImg](https://github.com/cas--/PasteImg) (mentioned in [Getting a graphic on the clipboard to the disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42996/getting-a-graphic-on-the-clipboard-to-the-disk)), but using `request_rich_text()` instead of `request_image()`? I wouldn't mind using a small Python script the rare times I want to get HTML source from the clipboard.

What's in the clipboard may actually be "rich text".

The Python script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571179/how-does-x11-clipboard-handle-multiple-data-formats/3571949#3571949) outputs

```
Current clipboard offers formats: ('TIMESTAMP', 'TARGETS', 'MULTIPLE',
'SAVE_TARGETS', 'COMPOUND_TEXT', 'STRING', 'TEXT', 'UTF8_STRING', 'text/html',
'text/plain')
```

Turns out my Pidgin logs are in HTML, so that's one way to get at *this* HTML source, bypassing the clipboard entirely. I'm still interested in the answer to the original question (how to retrieve HTML from the clipboard).

Comment: I don't understand pretty well. In the clipboard you have text plain. Why don't you just copy and past it? I think there is something I'm missing here.

Comment: So you are copying the formatted HTML from pidgin - e.g.  as **bold** instead of `<strong>bold</strong>`, but do you want to copy the HTML source so you can edit it, or do you want to edit after it was pasted into Thunderbird?

Comment: @Wilf, Both. Editing HTML source after pasting in Thunderbird would be ok, but having access to the actual HTML source on the clipboard would be even better because I could use that in a webpage or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! Here's how to get at the HTML source when there's some on your clipboard:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
print (gtk.Clipboard().wait_for_contents('text/html')).data
```

[This](http://pastebin.com/MLCT8PRD) helped.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346924/dump-x-clipboard-data-with-gtk-or-pygtk) didn't work for me. My callback was never entered.

Comment: i like this method best

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I need for Emacs org-mode: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/org-mode-parsing-rich-html-directly-when-pasting

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Python3/GTK3 though. `xclip -selection clipboard -o -t text/html` worked.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're trying to get at. Try pasting into something that takes wysiwyg, edit it there, then copy paste into Thunderbird?

Maybe bluegriffon or libreoffice writer will work.

Comment: If pasting it in does not allow it, you need to get to the HTML source first... you could search the folders in `.thunderbird` for a draft email an edit it.

Comment: Good ideas, thanks! See my recent answer--I figured out how to do it with PyGTK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modification of your script, which actually allows *editing* the html directly.

It also handles problems with character encoding: if you reply to an e-mail from someone using Windows, chances are the encoding is stuck in UTF-16, which is no good for 
editing. You may need to install the [`chardet` module](http://chardet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) in Python.

Replace `'vi'` with your text editor of choice, in `subprocess.call(...`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
import chardet
import os
import getopt
import subprocess

dtype = 'text/html'
htmlclip = gtk.Clipboard().wait_for_contents(dtype).data
encoding = chardet.detect(htmlclip)['encoding']

# Shove the clipboard to a temporary file
tmpfn = '/tmp/htmlclip_%i' % os.getpid()

with open (tmpfn, 'w') as editfile:
   editfile.write(htmlclip.decode(encoding))

# Manually edit the temporary file
subprocess.call(['vi', tmpfn])

with open (tmpfn, 'r') as editfile:
   htmlclip = editfile.read().encode(encoding)

# Put the modified data back to clipboard
gtk.Clipboard().set_with_data(
      [(dtype,0,0)],
      lambda cb, sd, info, data: sd.set(dtype, 8, htmlclip),
      lambda cb, d: None )
gtk.Clipboard().set_can_store([(dtype,0,0)])
gtk.Clipboard().store()
```

This does a full edit cycle, modifying the clipboard “in place”.

I use it to make up for Thunderbird's annoying lack of a html-editor feature:

1. *select all* with <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> in the message composing window
2. <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>
3. run the above script, which opens an editor –

   1. make your changes to the html source
   2. save and quit
4. <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> in the compose window overwrites the entire content with your html-edited version.

Comment: Maybe this works in thunderbird but I have problems to even re-paste copied unedited text (in my case in confluence)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use Thunderbird, but you should be able to use an extension to help edit the source in Thnderbird - e.g:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/edit-html-source/ <sup>*not been updated for ages*</sup>
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/stationery/

Comment: "Edit HTML Source" wasn't compatible with my version of Thunderbird. I did try Stationery, but I couldn't figure out how to view/edit HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261379/getting-html-source-or-rich-text-from-the-x-clipboard) at which directly uses the `xclip` utility:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t text/html
```

I find it the easiest and most reliable now, since GTK3/Python3 seems to have introduced some changes that broke the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTML source code of the "rich text":

```sh
# Get the HTML source to stdio
xclip -selection clipboard -t text/html -o
```

You have [several TARGETs](https://askubuntu.com/a/951312/349837), like text/plain (default) to get just the rendered text.

I manipulate the plain/text content of the clipboard using [`xsel`](https://github.com/kfish/xsel):

```
xsel -b | something | something_else | xsel -b
```

Pretty useful to for e.g. change a list to a TOP n cases, with `sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20`.

In your case change the first `xsel -b` with the above `xclip` command.