# Is it possible to screenshot a window without the frame?

Tags: screenshot

Can I screenshot a window without its frame so the Title, the Close, Minimize, Maximize Buttons and the System time will not be visible?
How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an application called [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/). You can use it to take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.

You can download the software directly from Ubuntu Software Center. Search for `Shutter`.

You can also go to [this](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/) link to view the installation instruction.

To exclude window decorator, go to:

```
Preferences -> Advanced -> Window Capture:
```

then uncheck *Include window decoration when capturing a window*

Also when you run the application, you can click on the Selection button to select a specific part of the window.

If you want to customize shortcuts to make it more suitable, thanks to User: Redbob for pointing it out, have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/252727/710635).

Comment: yes but does Shutter have an option specifically for this? If so, how do I select it? If not, how can I most easily approximate this effect? Also, since the app in in Ubuntu repositories, it can be installed with `sudo apt install shutter`. Is there a compelling reason to install it a different way?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it was on Ubuntu Software Center. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It is not necessary to install additional software to perform the action asked for in the question. There are plenty of additional apps that can do it as well, Shutter is a personal preference.

Comment: If you prefer, you can customize shortcuts to make it more suitable. Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool

Answer (score 15):

You can use custom screenshot area.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, then select the area you want.

Comment: this is pretty cool and saved a lot of time I usually spend in cropping.

Comment: While this is true, it does not accurately answer the question, as there is no guarantee to always get the full window frame every time. One must be exactly accurate when doing this, which can be quite difficult on high resolution screens (200+ dpi). One cannot select an area, adjust the selection, and then capture the result. Good for some things, like grabbing sections of a window, but not great for other things, like all of a window without the title bar.

Comment: This will generate a PNG on `~/Pictures`. With **C**trl to clipboard. More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/951312/349837)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, and no, depending on several factors. Applications which use client side decorations will not be able to hide the frame.

To take a screenshot without decorations, when it is possible to do so, you can run the screenshot tool from the dash (or `gnome-screenshot`), and select to *Grab the current window*, and then un-check the options for *Include the window border*.

You can also create a custom keyboard shortcut so that pressing the Print key, will open this app instead of automatically saving a screenshot, in *System Settings*.

Update 2022: The screenshot tool has been changed somewhat dramatically in recent GNOME releases, and the window border option is no longer there, as GNOME relies heavily on client side decorations and so there is no separation between the border and the window as such, any longer.

Comment: "and then un-check the options for Include the window border." recent version of this tool seems to have removed that option :-(

Answer (score 4):

A pure command line solution also suitable for scripts is `scrot`, which does not capture the window manager border by default when in window mode. To choose a window with your mouse (`-s`) and save a screenshot of it in `~/screenshot.png`, do:

```
scrot -s ~/screenshot.png
```

To save a screenshot of the then active window (`-u`) in `~/screenshot.png` 5 seconds after you started the command (`-d 5`) and automatically open it in `gimp` (`-e 'gimp $f'`) afterwards, do:

```
scrot -u -d 5 ~/screenshot.png -e 'gimp $f'
```

#### Further reading

- [`man scrot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/scrot.1.html)