# Clipboard issue on Ubuntu Arzt

Tags: libreoffice, xfce, clipboard, bricscad

I've had problems with Arful...
One of them (the most important right now) is  a clipboard issue. Artful's clipboard doesn't work properly 'cause using libreoffice it didn't copy an image to the clipboard from another document. I don't remember wich was the document's extension, but it happended.
I installed clipman in XFCE (my preferred desktop environment) to make a drawing in BricsCAD and it gave me that copyclip issue also.
When I write an existing drawing, it works. But if I make a drawing copying another one, it breaks.
I want to know if there's a low-level clipboard manager to test BricsCAD issue. I really need BricsCAD, and it could be a problem of Artful.
I've already requested technical support to Bricsys Co., but they didn't solve me that trouble...
I'm running kernel 4.15.1, XFCE, compiz and the last stable mesa from Padoka Stable (17.3.2)

Comment: Can you put more effort in restructuring your question. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Clipboard has a weird behavior... Using BricsCAD it doesn't work at all... I wonder if it could be an Artful's issue 'cause I had a paste issue about three months ago with Ubuntu.

Comment: see [this xclip command](https://askubuntu.com/a/951312/712203) to see if the image is in the clipboard at all. Try to analyze the problem with 2 different programs that should normally work (e.g. shotwell) and the re-edit your question. Also try using one of gnome/kde/openbox on a fresh install (using e.g. virt-manager) to find out if it is a problem of XFCE.
In the current state your question it is totally unclear.